# WiFi with static IP configuration

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, static-ip

I want to connect to my home wifi, which has a static IP configuration.
I Have tried to set up the connection both using the GUI of network manager and by editing the network interface file, but in neither case I managed to connect to the internet.

The specifics of the configuration are:

- IP address: 10.149.40.49
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 10.149.40.1
- DNS: 10.149.32.2, 10.156.33.53

I know that this configuration works because I managed to connect to the internet using these parameters with both my phone and my other server running arch.
But when I try to connect with my ubuntu server, I do successfully connect to the WiFi but i cannot resolve or ping any website.
No problem arises when I try to connect to non-static networks.
I am clueless on how to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ ip route
  default via 10.149.32.2 dev wlp5s0  proto static  metric 600 
  10.149.32.2 dev wlp5s0  proto static  scope link  metric 600 
  10.149.40.0/24 dev wlp5s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.149.40.49 metric 600 
  169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp5s0  scope link  metric 1000
```

Comment: Sorry, yes a typo the IP is 10.149.40.49. All the other parameters are correct though. These parameters were given to me, and they always worked so far, so I'm not sure if they are supposed to be different.

Comment: The output of something like `ip route` might be helpful as well

Comment: Yes, I also think that that's the issue, but I can't figure out why. I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @ElioMonaco I didn't think it would, unless the gateway is also a DNS server.  Edit your question and add what steeldriver above has asked.

Comment: @Terrance yes, sorry if it's getting confusion, I am nit used in using this forums. The ip route output was incorrect, since i forgot to disconnect the router i am now using to communicate. I added the actual output of the static router. I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please add to your question your Ubuntu version and flavor.  Different Ubuntu versions defaulted to different ways of configuring your network.  As it shows it looks as though your WiFi got a DHCP address.

Comment: It looks like you have the default route / gateway set to one of your DNS addresses somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (exchange wlp5s0 with your interface name):

Flush your configuration: `sudo ip addr flush wlp5s0`

Set your own configuration: `sudo ip addr 10.149.40.49/24 broadcast 10.149.40.255 dev wlp5s0`

Add a default route via your gateway: `sudo ip route add default via 10.149.40.1`

Add your dns-nameservers to resolv.conf: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 10.149.32.2
nameserver 10.156.33.53
```

**All these settings will be lost after reboot.**